# Unity iOS build black screen

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build an iOS project from Unity and get a black screen. I'm following this process, https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing I can get the project to build to the device but there seems to be a runtime error I'm unsure how to fix.

https://gist.github.com/mmeister1203/8b330c712dacc11f7e910c2085331a29

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Unity standard shader or custom one?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the project. I assume it's using the standard shader

Comment: Ok. What project is this? link? I know you are running Unity 5.5.0b4 from the log but what iOS version are you running this on?

Comment: It's the Simple Mobile Placeholder project in the Asset store. I've tried building to iOS 9 & 10 same result